# how to move clock to the middle of Unity panel in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: clock

I want to move the clock into the middle of Unity panel (U 12.04) to make it looks like in Luna OS. Anyone who can do it, share the way, please!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the Gnome panel , it is not possible to right select and move applets on the Unity panel .

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to move clock into the middle of Unity panel.  But in Gnome, you can move all the Applets to the middle of the screen.  Hold you <kbd>Alt</kbd>and press the right mouse button, once you get the drop down menu, click on move and drag it to the middle of the screen.

[image]

Or you can add a new clock applet, by holding you <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and pressing the right mouse button, click on add to Panel, and choose clock, then you can move it to the middle of the panel, like the way shown above.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think this serves as answer to the **UNITY TOP PANEL**, but to gnome panel maybe.

Comment: @tijybba, Thanks, I fixed it to reflect that. I was testing on Gnome, but ...head not feeling ok