# How to center date time in top panel?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I'm running 12.04 with Gnome.  If needed, I can switch to Unity to do the fix.

I've got 2 desktops running 12.04.  One has the current date/time with the icons at the upper right(default).  The other has date/time in the center of the top panel(I made this happen).  I want both computers to have the date/time at the center.  How did I do that?

I know that I changed something to move the date/time on one computer.  But I don't remember what I did.

I tried several different searches but did not find an answer.

Comment: Take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/156076/how-to-move-clock-to-the-middle-of-unity-panel-in-ubuntu-12-04/156089#156089

Comment: @Andy Arnold you are using Gnome Shell or Unity? In GNome Shell center is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Hold alt and right click the clock, then a menu will come up. Choose move, and move the applet until it hits the center. Done.